# type Error : 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I can't find the problem. 
It's ALL about the **Williams Accumulation Distribution financial analysis** indicator. It "supposedly" represents the amount of buying and selling in the market.

```
def wadl(prices, periods):
   results = holder()
   dict = {}
   for i in range(0,len(periods)):
       WAD = []
       for j in range(periods[i],len(prices)-periods[i]):            
           CC = prices.close.iloc[j]
           CL = prices.close.iloc[j-1]
           # TR high = max(current high,previous close)
           TRH = np.array([prices.high.iloc[j],CL]).max()
           TRL = np.array([prices.low.iloc[j],CL]).min()


           if  CC > CL :
               PM = CC - TRL

           elif CC < CL :
               PM = CC - TRH

           elif CC == CL :
               PM = 0

           else :
               print('unkown error ocurred, see administrator')

           AD = PM*prices.AskVol.iloc[j]
           WAD = np.append(WAD,AD)

       WAD = WAD.cumsum()
       WAD = pd.DataFrame(WAD, index=prices.iloc[periods[i]:-periods[i]].index)
       WAD.columns = ['close']
       dict[periods[i]] = WAD

   results.wadl= dict
   return results
```

Comment: This code is not indented properly - notice the code immediately under `def wadl(prices, periods):` isn't indented. Everything within that function should be further indented than that line. Also, what have you tried? Can you show an example where you call the function, and also print the error trace? That should help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is at line `results.wadl= dict` as here, `wadl` is a function but you are assigning a dictionary object `dict` to a callable function `wadl`.